# Closing TabItem by clicking middle button

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I have a problem.
In my WPF application, if i press a tabItem with middle mouse button, this tabItem should close. Just like in FireFox.
But I try to do this using MVVM, and i need to use commands. Also my tabItems are created dynamically.
Help me plz!
Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `DataTemplate` for your tab items like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabTemplate">
  <Border>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.InputBindings>
         <MouseBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Gesture="MiddleClick" />
      </Grid.InputBindings>
      <!-- the actual contents of your tab item -->
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

In your application window, add a the close command

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" Executed="CloseCommandExecuted" CanExecute="CloseCommandCanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

and finally assign the data template as item template to your tab control.

Comment: When I handle the CloseCommandExecuted, e.Source returns a TabControl object. How do I get the TabItem object?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [`MouseBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding.aspx) to some [`InputBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings.aspx) perhaps?

Comment: My tabItems are created dynamically. Should I add a mouseBinding in code behind?

Comment: @Yevgeniy: That would be one option, bit unfortunately that this cannot be done via style...

Answer (score 0):

**Closing a TabItem (Not Selected) - TabControl**

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControlUser" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- this is the header template-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="ExtraBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Image Source="/Images/RedClose.png" Width="22" Height="22" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10 0 0 0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <!-- this is the body of the TabItem template-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UserControl Content="{Binding UserControl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
```

**C# Code - Image MouseDown Click Event**

```
try
        {
            int matches = 0;
            DependencyObject dependency = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
            // Traverse the visual tree looking for TabItem
            while ((dependency != null) && !(dependency is TabItem))
                dependency = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependency);
            if (dependency == null)
            {
                // Didn't find TabItem
                return;
            }
            TabItem selectedTabItem = dependency as TabItem;
            var selectedTabContent = selectedTabItem.Content as MainWindowViewModel.TabItem;
            foreach (var item in MainWindowViewModel.Tabs)
            {
                if (item.Header == selectedTabContent.Header)
                {
                    matches = MainWindowViewModel.Tabs.IndexOf(item);
                }
            }
            MainWindowViewModel.Tabs.RemoveAt(matches);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((System.Action)(() => new View.MessageBox(ex.Message).ShowDialog()));
        }
```

This event finds with the exact Mouse clicked position (as TabItem)and this will remove
MainWindowViewModel.Tabs.RemoveAt(matches); the TabItem(even if it is not selected).